# closed loop zero in second order PLL with a proportional-integral filter

Tags: rf, transfer-function, pll

Why does the closed-loop zero in second-order PLL with a PI filter enhance the phase noise near PLL bandwidth frequency? I know that it enhances the phase margin but i can't find the logic behind why it enhances the PHASE NOISE and also that why this zero causes the 'continued increase in phase error' even when the feedback is trying to correct it??? and also why don't the DLLs have this problem of 'jitter accumulation', in other words?

Comment: I don't know, but I've been reading "Phaselock Techniques" by Floyd Gardener, https://www.amazon.com/Phaselock-Techniques-Floyd-M-Gardner/dp/0471430633. Which is a pretty good book on the subject.  (You can find the second ed. much cheaper.)

Comment: First-order PLLs have no integrating capacitor, thus static phase error can be large. Second-order PLLs do have that integration of the error, and the loop seeks to drive the error to be close to zero radians. To establish damping, one approach has resistor in series with the integration capacitor. To reduce that jitter (phasenoise), often a capacitor is added in parallel with the dampening resistor.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf thanks for your reply but I have difficulty understanding what you said, slow variations in the period of input frequency (slow jitter) propagates to the output unattenuated and if it's a fast variation, the PLL will miss it. but how can the resistor in series with a capacitor (which increase the type and introduce a ZERO), attenuate this input jitter?   and if the loop is locked and the phase error approaches to zero, it means we'll have less peaking?? This 2nd capacitor is in parallel with the series capacitor and resistor increases the roll-off of the loop filter,

Comment: so decreases the reference spur, but what about the role of that zero caused by the resistor and capacitor in decreasing the phase noise?@analogsystemsrf